# Assembly OFFSET used twice in one instruction, what is offset of offset?

Tags: assembly, offset, tasm

I am working on a project in Assembly in which a certain weird property of `offset` instruction appeared. I wrote down the following instruction:

`mov ax, offset offset variable`

When I executed the program, I expected an error, but the program ran without showing any errors and the line `mov ax, offset offset variable` appeared in the debugging tool as `mov ax, 0784`, which is the same way that the instruction `mov ax, offset variable` appears (0784 is the offset of *variable* in the data segment). After being confused for a moment, I executed this instruction: `mov ax, offset offset offset offset offset offset variable` (yes, a bit funny) and it had the same effect and the same result (ax value became the offset of the variable)

My questions are why is the value stored in register AX is the offset of the variable (can I be sure that always offset offset = offset?), why those lines do not produce any errors? And, if there is a meaning for **offset of offset**, what is the meaning of it? (the meaning which assembler follows in these examples)

Thanks.
I am using assembly x86, TASM, DOSBox emulator, and Turbo Debugger if it is relevant :)

Comment: There is no meaning, it's probably just a bug (or feature) in the parser. Funnily enough even the gnu assembler accepts multiple `offset` instances.

Comment: @Jester, in that case, is that a feature that I can trust and use? (I mean that N times of offset will be just the same as one offset). And, do I need to try and avoid using this bug, or not to worry and use it? (I have a very specific code case, in which this bug helps)

Comment: Your code is likely specific to the assembler anyway, and tasm isn't going to get new revisions. But in general, if it's not documented I'd rather not depend on it.

Comment: I think you can be sure that if it’s not an error, the extraneous “offset” is ignored. There’s no other meaning that it could have. So you don’t need to fix it unless you start getting assembler errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of `variable` isn't itself stored in memory anywhere, adding more `offset` keywords isn't going to create pointer objects and give you the address of a pointer to a pointer to `variable.`

**It's clearly just the same as using `offset` *once*.**  That's presumably a quirk of the parser in TASM: I'd guess that the parsing logic sees `offset` and sets a flag internally, then starts parsing again until it gets to a variable name.  If it sees `offset` again, it just sets the same flag again and keeps going.

There's no reason or benefit to write code this way, so don't do it intentionally.  Possibly it's convenient for making macros that work regardless of specifying `offset` or not when you call it?  Beyond that, keep your source simple.

(Fun fact: the GNU assembler also doesn't reject this, in `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode.  I still doubt this is an intentional feature, just an undocumented quirk.)

Comment: Thank You! The macro scenario which you have mentioned is exactly the reason which I had gotten to this question! (I must say that it is pretty impressive that you have figured it out based only on my short description). Anyways, do you think that a better programming habit is to separate the cases into two different macros in order to avoid the quirk? One macro which takes as parameter the **offset of var** and one which takes only the **name of the var** (and inside uses OFFSET), or do you think it doesn't matter/better to treat the bug as a feature and stay with one macro for both cases?

Comment: @GiladKustin: I think it would depend on the situation, like how you expect users of your macro to think about it.  If it can take a symbol name and both uses the value in memory there *and* uses the address, then just take the symbol name and use offset internally.  If you only ever use the address (offset), and could take a numeric constant or a register instead, let the user ("caller") use `foo OFFSET bar` or `foo eax` or whatever.